# Why the parameter 'proxy' is not used in jdk dynamic proxy implement?

Tags: proxy, java

I read the sample about proxy here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html

As you can see, the parameter 'proxy' in the method of 'invoke' is not used. What is the proxy used for? Why not use it here: result = m.invoke(**proxy**, args); ?

```
public class DebugProxy implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

private Object obj;

public static Object newInstance(Object obj) {
return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
    obj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
    new DebugProxy(obj));
}

private DebugProxy(Object obj) {
this.obj = obj;
}

public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
throws Throwable
{
    Object result;
try {
    System.out.println("before method " + m.getName());
    result = m.invoke(obj, args);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw e.getTargetException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " +
                   e.getMessage());
} finally {
    System.out.println("after method " + m.getName());
}
return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proxy is specially constructed by JVM "dynamic proxy" class. Your code can't invoke directly it's method. Alternative way to think about this is that proxy is "interface", invoking *any* method on it correspond to invoking `public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)` method, so invoking method on proxy will end with infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why we have the parameter since we can not use it. Why not hidden it?

Comment: Why to hide if it takes no cost to show. :-)
Maybe you want to introspect this class (for example, to call getClass() method).